# How to initialize many properties in class?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a class Store with many properties.

```
class Store {
  readonly id: NonNullable<string>;
  address: string;
  // more 20 properties
 
  constructor(data: Store) {
    const {
      id,
      address,
      // more 20 properties
    } = data;
 
    this.id = id;
    this.address = (address && address.trim()) || null;
    // more 20 properties
  }
}
```

Is there any best approaches for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

You should be able to do this with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
constructor(data: Store) {
   this = Object.assign(this, data);
   // other complex assignments / trimming etc...
   // ...
}
```